# Is this a sahih hadith: "They are those who accumulated wealth without differentiating between lawful and unlawful..."?

Tags: hadith, money, authenticity, miraj

Prophet narrated:

> On the Night of Mi'raj, I saw people lying on their backs with drum-like, transparent bellies where there are all kinds of creatures. I asked my brother Jibrail, "What are they?" He replied, "O the Messenger of Allah, they are from your Ummah [community, nation]." I asked again, "What is their guilt?" He answered, "They are those who accumulated wealth without differentiating between lawful and unlawful means and who did not think whether the money they earned was lawful or unlawful. The unlawful substances they consumed turned to this state in their bodies."

This hadith can be found on [My Religion Islam](http://www.myreligionislam.com/detail.asp?aid=5969).

Is this a sahih hadith?

Comment: Could your provide at least a kind of source for that?

Comment: I could not find this hadith anywhere apart from in the link provided; nowhere t o be found in collections of hadiths or anywhere else on the Internet (with this wording). Without additional information, it will be impossible to find this hadith.

Comment: @III-AK-III I've found this link https://grandmaskittens.com/tags/hadith/2 which by now doesn't seem to be accessible while doing my research I have no plan whether it contains any additional information or not.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I tried looking for the link you provided through CachedView, but the page seems not to have been archived through Google Cache or Archive.org. I guess it will be difficult to find the source of this hadith.